# C# The context is not currently tracking the entity error APi . on update method

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, owin

I'm newbie on c# and I am using OData and Owinselfhost the problem is when I try to make an **update** to my Object Person always get this error msg

`The context is not currently tracking the entity`

[image]

**My controller**

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route()]
    // PUT api/people/5 
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]Person value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value updated " + value.LastName);
        var result = api.updatePerson(value);
        if (result == false)
            return BadRequest("An error occurred");
        return Ok("Person updated");
    }
```

**API service**

```
 public bool updatePerson(Person p)
        {
            try
            {
                var ctx = GetAppControlContext();
                Person person = new Person();
                person = ctx.People.Where(ps => ps.Id == p.Id).SingleOrDefault();
                if (person != null)
                {
                    //person.FirstName = p.FirstName;
                    person = p;

                    Console.WriteLine("Name" + person.FirstName);                    
                    ctx.UpdateObject(person); 
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("person updated");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**PS** 
It work only if I assign to person field by field like this

```
 public bool updatePerson(Person p)
        {
            try
            {
                var ctx = GetAppControlContext();
                Person person = new Person();
                person = ctx.People.Where(ps => ps.Id == p.Id).SingleOrDefault();
                if (person != null)
                {
                  person.FirstName = p.FirstName;
                  person.LastName= p.LastName;
                  person.age= p.age;

                    Console.WriteLine("Name" + person.FirstName);                    
                    ctx.UpdateObject(person); 
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("person updated");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and this not a practical way for me because i have several field !

AppConrolContext

```
    public AppControlContext GetAppControlContext()
    {
        var appContext = new AppControlContext(ServerAppControl)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _password)
        };

        return appContext;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right your code only works if you assign each field individually and that's the way it is. because `Person` is Reference Type.

You have two instance of `Person`, `p` and `person` and these variables are just pointer to your instances. when you write `person = p;` both of the pointers are pointing to the same instance which is not tracking by your context.

so you need to assign each fields, but if you have a lot of filed you can use `AutoMapper` to ease your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `context.Entry(Object).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

In your case you have ctx as Context so
(read comments for explanation)

```
public bool updatePerson(Person p)
{
  try
    {
      var ctx = GetAppControlContext();
      //if it exists then we can change the state to modified
      if (ctx.People.Any(ps => ps.Id == p.Id))
      {
        //This will attach the entity to the context
        //Will also mark it so it will be saved in SaveChanges();
        ctx.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("person updated");
        return true;
      }

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      return false;
    }
  return false;
}
```

**Edit**

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) for further explanation and more States explained.

Comment: Are you sure because it seems my compiler reject this line **context.Entry(Object).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;**  with the ** appCotrolContext does not have a definition for 'entry'  and no extention method 'Entry'**  ..  I Updated my question with AppControlContext code

Comment: @Dev i hope you used the complete `updatePerson()` which i suggested. The line at the top is just a example how it looks like. For your case its `ctx.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: my compiler reject this line **context.Entry(Object).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;**  with the ** appCotrolContext does not have a definition for 'entry'  and no extention method 'Entry'**  ..  I Updated my question with AppControlContext code

Comment: @Dev You need `YourClass : DbContext` for .Entry.

Comment: @Dev what class is your DbContext?

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan I'm not sure that he is using `entityframework`, I think he is using `linq to sql`

Comment: @Dev if Kahbazi is correct then ignore my solution. I don't know much of linq to sql srry.